# Ball falling through viscous fluid experiment - strange results

Tags: fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, viscosity

I did an experiment in which I dropped three different sized spherical beads (4mm, 6mm, and 11mm diameter) with the same densities through a viscous liquid (a water-detergent solution). They all fell the same distance, but the biggest one fell a full ten seconds faster than the smallest one. What could be the explanation for this? I would have thought the opposite due to friction and the fact that gravity affects everything the same. Why did the biggest one fall fastest?

Comment: The first results will already answer your question: https://www.google.com/search?num=100&source=hp&q=ball+in+viscous+fluid+experiment

Comment: @stafusa ironically, first result now goes to this question :)

Comment: @Lope, see, I told the search answered the question ;-P More seriously, it's interesting how it became the first google result in less than 24h.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have pointed out the difference between rain drops (large radius) and mist drops (small radius) which fall much slower.

When terminal velocity $v$ is reached the viscous drag on a sphere of density $\rho$ and radius $r$, $6\pi r v \eta$, is equal to the apparent weight of the sphere $\frac 43\pi r^3 (\rho -\sigma)g$ where $\sigma$ is the density of the fluid and $\eta$ its viscosity.

From this you get that $v \propto r^2$.

Comment: Rain drops won't be in the Stokes drag, but in the Newton drag regime (inertial term important).

Comment: @VladimirF I agree but I thought that the analogy was a reasonable one to make to illustrate what was observed in a viscous liquid.